# New security protocol from Yahoo

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, yahoo-mail

Does anyone know which security protocol yahoo is using? It isn't mentioned in [this article](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account/SLN27791.html). I only know that neither Thunderbird nor Outlook 2010 are working if I enable the proposed security setting.

Currently IMAP with SSL/TLS is used. Do I need another authentication method? Or which email client does work with the new security setting?

Comment: Save yourself the hassle, and leave yahoo for a better provider.  They have violated responsible disclosure rules twice, was is to say they are not hiding even worse things they haven't disclosed.

Comment: The only security that really exits for IMAP is SSL/TLS...Yahoo on their backend can detect your device type and require "device passwords" in place of your 2FA.  TLS and 2FA are not connected

Comment: @cybernard: I saw [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/606406/feasibility-of-transferring-email-from-yahoo-to-gmail-using-imap-and-pc-email-cl) before and it looks interesting. I know it's another question, but how does the swap looks like? Leave the account as mentioned in the post and install a forwarding rule?

Comment: @Ramhound: So I should enable 2FA so that I can manage the devices?

Comment: That's not what I am saying

Comment: @testing log into gmail.  Settings->Account and import.  Import contacts and mail.  Enter the source information as requested and everything is imported.

Comment: @cybernard: So this is using IMAP to access the other accounts emails? What should happen with the yahoo account in the long term? If I would redirect now, I would get the email twice.

Comment: @testing once gmail or whatever has everything imported.  Delete every scrap of information in the yahoo account.  Forward emails.  Send out an email to all your contact "Please update your records, now on I will be using me@gmail.com.  Also delete any references to <name>@yahoo.com".  After everyone has updated their records, change the password to something secure.  Leave it for approx 3 mos to make sure all your contact got the message.  You need to make sure all websites you have logins at are updated.  Then delete the account.

Comment: Some people say keep the account empty so someone else can't claim it, and then use it to reset a password for another account that still has your old email.